# is it transform operation make a single RDD in Dstream

Tags: scala, apache-spark

when I am using spark streaming ,I don't reallyunderstand transform operation，here is my code:

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("streaming").setMaster("local[4]")
val ssc = new StreamingContext(conf, Seconds(1))
val mDstream = 
  ssc
   .socketTextStream(args(0), 9999).flatMap(x => x.split(" "))
   .map((_, 1))
   .reduceByKeyAndWindow((a: Int, b: Int) => (a + b), Seconds(10), Seconds(3))
   .transform(rdd => {
      rdd.sortBy(_._2, false)
    })
```

I want to Know how many RDDs in the mDstream?
appreciate that!

Answer (score 1):

`transform` is a method which runs on the driver side, that is how it is able to take in an `RDD` as its input parameter. Note that the sort will still run in parallel foreach partition inside the `RDD`. There will be a single `RDD` in a single job running your streaming job.

Comment: So when I add ”.foreachRDD(rdd => {
      println("RDD")
    })“，how many RDD will be print in console??

Comment: will I get actually one "RDD" a time?

Comment: @Gpwner Yes, one at a time.